# What characters can I send in an HTTP response body using NodeJS and Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a node express app responding to an ajax post from the browser client-side. I am wondering what are invalid characters to send in this http response body.

I have set the response header to use charset=utf-8. My operating system is Ubuntu with a locale charmap of UTF-8 as well. The problem is, we are constructing our response using dynamic and mathematical manipulation of charcodes via [string.prototype.charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)() and [string.prototype.fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)(). I remember when I used to mess with ASCII, many characters were control characters. Some would mean tab and some would mean backspace which would always mangle the text.

If I construct a string using char codes, then send it to the client as UTF-8, which char codes would be invalid to send to the client, if any? Unfortunately, I'm coming from windows. I decided to learn Linux and it's a hard road but I'm making progress. Thanks.

Comment: Did you look up what a UTF-8 encoding means?  It's all spelled out in the spec and other articles describing that.

Comment: I have read it over and over LOL

Comment: And, what part of that did you not understand?  It is all spelled out there.

Comment: What can the browser not receive? Some characters mean delete and tab... Don't want it to mangle the http response

Comment: Might want to read this: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: I wish someone would explain the downvote so I can understand what it is about my question they do not like.

Comment: @jfriend00 I will read that link.... however, based on the length of the article the subject would not be as simple as one may perceive. Thanks.

Comment: Your question shows no evidence that you've read the spec or any articles about the UTF-8 format. You should spend some time attempting to understand the spec and then ask a more specific question about something in the specification you don't understand.  Questions don't work well here when you just ask us to explain things where there are already hundreds of articles and specifications written about it.  It does nobody any good for us to just copy/paste existing information into an answer.  Instead, you should read what's already out there and ask a more specific question about that info.

Comment: You also don't describe the actual problem you're trying to solve.  What exactly are you trying to send to the browser and what do you want the browser to do with it when it receives it?

Comment: whatever.........

Comment: I'm offering you advice on how to ask a good question here that gets a good and quick answer.  You probably got downvoted because you ignored that advice.  You asked why you got downvoted - I attempted to explain.  Remind me to avoid attempting to help you next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-8 can encode any valid unicode character. `String.charCodeAt()` returns UTF-16 encoded unicode character values, and `String.fromCharCode` constructs a string from a sequence of unicode characters, so at all times you should have a valid unicode string which can be properly encoded to UTF-8. Control characters aren't a problem in the string representation, but might be a problem if you print the string e.g. to a console.

Comment: great... so the control characters only mangle the content when you try to print it to the screen, right? so in the pipe from server to browser it would be received accurately in memory on the client.

Comment: @wayofthefuture Yes, because control characters are still valid unicode characters. They conventionally are used to control things in a terminal - e.g. print a new line or make a bell sound - hence the name - so printing them to a console can have effects other than displaying a character on the screen.